# Advice on Noise in Square Input Signal

Tags: signal, signal-processing, signal-integrity, signal-to-noise

I am reading the following signal from an open drain output, and trying to read the signal frequency. However, I am getting short spikes in the wave as seen below, and this is messing with the reading of my microcontroller. Any advice on how to filter this noise? Thank you [image]

Answer (score 0):

any low-pass filtering will do. Say, your signal frequency is 1 kHz, and these spikes are less than 5 µs long: a low-pass filter with a cut-off frequency above 11 kHz will not hurt your signal significantly, but remove the spikes.